# Async task inside parallel.for loop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have an async method being called from with `Parallel.For` code below. Now looking at the code it is pretty straight forward with the exception JsonParse class has an static method all it does is calls the web service to download json string and converts that to an PairResults object and returns.

The issue I am having is the `Parallel.For` loop never exits, I can clearly see the data is coming from the webcall "item.part1=data.value" all working fine, but updateAllResults never finishes. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void updateAllResults()
{ 
    Parallel.For(0, PairList.Count(), (i) =>
    {            
         var item = PairList[i];
         var data = (Parse.JsonParse<PairResults>
                             .getJsonString("http://localhost:22354/" 
                                                        + item.Original)).Result;
         item.part1 = data.value;
    }); 
}
```

Comment: It should finish, but it could take a long time depending on the number of items in PairList. That being said, consider making this truly async by using `async (i) =>` and `await` without the `.Result` call.

Comment: Ah that worked like magic. changing the method to async (i) => was the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an anti-patern for `Parallel.For`, because you're using it only to start async operations and block on them. This way, it will block a limited number of pool threads, and the actual level of parallelism may be much lower than if you were using tasks instead:

```
public void updateAllResults()
{
    var tasks = PairList.Select(async (item) => 
    {
        var data = await Parse.JsonParse<PairResults>
            .getJsonString("http://localhost:22354/" + item.Original).
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        item.part1 = data.value;
    });

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Also, your question is tagged with [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) tag. Both `Parallel.For` and the above code will block your UI thread, if you use it in a WinForms app. The right solution would be to use `Task.WhenAll`:

```
public async Task updateAllResults()
{
    var tasks = PairList.Select(async (item) => 
    {
        var data = await Parse.JsonParse<PairResults>
            .getJsonString("http://localhost:22354/" + item.Original)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        item.part1 = data.value;
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

// button click handler
async void button_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    this.button.Enabled = false;
    try
    {
        await updateAllResults()
    }
    finally
    {
        this.button.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Parallel.For blocks until all iterations have been executed or there is a break from the loop just like a regular `for` statement. Make sure that all the data has been downloaded. After that the `Parallel.For` should finish and consequentially the method too.