# Parallel.Foreach and Task conflict

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I am uploading images to cloud in Parallel execution as :

```
// Make a TaskFactory that will use the UI thread's context
var uiFactory = new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

Parallel.ForEach(FinalFileNames,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
    path =>
    {
         count++;
         /* Calculate percentage of upload done */
         double iPercentDone = (int)(((float)count / iTotalFiles) * 100);

        // Send the progress report to the UI thread.
        uiFactory.StartNew(() =>
        UploadProgress.Value = iPercentDone;

        LblProgress.Content = count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                               + " file(s) uploaded from " + iTotalFiles +
                     " file(s)";
                        }
       });
```

The problem I am facing is, the UI is blocked when I am doing this. The reason seems to be working in the same thread..

If I do wrap this Parallel.ForEach in "Task.Factory.New", that its making the async calls, which is not my requirement.

Please let me know, How can I fix the UI block issue, as well as not making the calls async.

Comment: Have you tried Application.DoEvents(); after every foreach?

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` is not intended for IO-bound tasks like image uploads. A similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22403856/1768303

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - Please see the edit..I added the uifactory definition..

Comment: @Noseratio - But I dont see any problem with Parallel.Foreach here..I can wrap that to a task..but the problem is what I outlined..Please advise

Comment: You'll properly need to run your parallel.foreach in a background worker thread, to avoid it blocking your UI thread

Comment: @Akon, http://stackoverflow.com/a/22497438/1768303

Answer (score 2):

The `Parallel.Foreach` when started from UI thread will block the UI thread until finished, so the Tasks started will queue up but will not run until UI thread returns to its message loop.

One way would be to run `Parallel.Foreach` in another thread using `Task.Run()`, better way is to use async/await in combination with `IProgress<T>`

See

- http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/07/04/async-operations-and-progress-updates/comment-page-1/
- http://tutorials.csharp-online.net/Progress_Reporting_Patterns

Comment: I think this is an async approach, but I want to update the UI only after the file is uploaded..How to achieve that

Comment: You should not be blocking UI thread during file upload, this will get the application into "Not responding" state. Async approach is what you need.

Comment: `await Task.Run(() => { Parallel.Foreach(...) })`